# Single Choice Questions

Tags: gwt, gwt-celltable

I want to do a Single Choice Questions (or Single Choice Test) in GWT. So I need rows with only one checkbox selected per row.

How do I make a single selection? I thought about a SingleSelectionModel, but it can only be applied on a CellTable, not on a row.

I want a sort of "CheckBoxGroupCell", but I haven't found anything relevant on the web.

Thanks for your help!

**Edit:**

This is my solution for a MultipleChoice test:

```
Column<EvaluationDto, Boolean> getRadioButtonColumn(final int mark) {
    return new Column<EvaluationDto, Boolean>(new CheckboxCell(true, false)) {

        @Override
        public Boolean getValue(EvaluationDto object) {
            return object.getMark() == mark ? true : false;
        }

        @Override
        public void render(Cell.Context context, EvaluationDto eval, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
            RadioButton r = new RadioButton("");
            // sur une ligne un seul radioButton sera selectionné
            r.setName(eval.getQuestion().getCategory().getTitle() + eval.getQuestion().getTitle());
            SafeHtml html = SafeHtmlUtils.fromTrustedString(r.toString());
            sb.append(html);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent, EvaluationDto object, NativeEvent event) {
            super.onBrowserEvent(context, parent, object, event);
            object.setMark(mark);
        }
    };
}
```

And in css

```
input[type="radio"] {
-webkit-appearance: checkbox;
-moz-appearance: checkbox;
-ms-appearance: checkbox;     
-o-appearance: checkbox;      }
```

change all radiosButton to checkbox. (Don't work on ie)

After i just retrive all EvaluationDto (mark has been updated).

Comment: If you want some single selection, you should use radio buttons instead of checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

The widget in GWT for this is `RadioButton`, take a look to the [showcase](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwRadioButton)

To use it in data grids, you can take this [RadioButtonCell example](http://thoughtsofthree.com/2011/02/creating-a-gwt-radiobuttoncell/).

For more info about this issue, you can read this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/81TG4Ny8DFY) or this [one](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-web-toolkit/radiocell/google-web-toolkit/Yik_EXu_wU0/5EZpViyy8O8J).

Comment: Thank you for your help, but in a basic single choice test you have no radiobutton. I found a css solution to have a "checkbox style". [link](http://jsfiddle.net/mq8Zq/). I going to overide render to do radioButton with same class and onBrowserEvent to retrieve my value.

Comment: why dont you have radio button?, the link you sent is actually a radio-button (obviously with a changed  style)